# ServiceStack iterate through all request/response DTO

Tags: c#, extjs, servicestack, sencha-architect, servicestack-bsd

How can I iterate through all request/response DTOs that are setup with a route?

For example a route like this:

```cs
[Route("/api/something", "GET")]
public class SomethingGetRequest : IReturn<List<Something>>
{
    public int SomethingId { get; set; }
}
```

and Response DTO like this:

```cs
public class Something
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

I want to have a service action where I can iterate through all setup routes, and
retrieve the:

- Request URL
- Class name
- Request properties
- Response DTO properties

Is there some Servicstack built in way to do this?

In the end I would like to use this to autogenerate ExtJS Store/Models.
I'm also interested in a better/alternative approach.

**EDIT:**

Here is the solution I came up with: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8773475/9d02a86d8c651649dd3b5af93e5ffc539eeeb4ac#file-gistfile1-txt)

On the `/extjs/javascript` route the service returns extjs store/models and
on the `/extjs/metadata` route the service returns a zip file with a store/model folder you can drop in a newly created Sencha Architect project. 
The templates are based on what Architect v. 3.0.1.1343 produces.

This assumes a route decorated like this:

```cs
[Route("/api/something", "GET", Summary="route description")]
public class SomethingGetRequest : IReturn<List<Something>>
{

    [ApiMember(Name = "SomethingId", ParameterType = "query", IsRequired = true, DataType = "int")]
    public string SomethingId { get; set; }

}
```

The current implementation only works for simple properties in request/response DTOs. There is room for improvement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the [ServiceStack.Api.Swagger](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger) package (documented [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API))? That sounds pretty similar to what you want.

If the Swagger UI won't work for you out of the box, you could use the ServiceStack.Api.Swagger package and send requests to `/resources` and its related URLs to get all the metadata in JSON format and then process that data according to your needs. Or if you want to write something in C#, consult the [code](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Api.Swagger) for SwaggerApiService and SwaggerResourcesService to see how it retrieves all DTOs and routes and extracts metadata about them.

Comment: Thank you! That looks like a good idea. I'm going to look into the `/resources` request. I should get all needed information from there. :)

Comment: I've managed to get the needed information from the `/resources` request. Can I edit your answer later to include my code?

Comment: If you can include the code in a [gist](https://gist.github.com), you could add a comment with a link to that. Otherwise you could add the code to your original question content perhaps.